# Algorithm to resolve multiple many-many exclusions

Tags: sql, algorithm

I want to find and delete rows that fulfill a dependency, but only if all siblings also fulfill that dependency. Children can also have multiple parents, which makes this kind of hairy but here comes the full explanation:

I'm working on a legacy system with a pretty awful data structure which I have no options to do anything about. The below is a simplification of the problem, but I think it is the best way to explain it.

As regards what I'm trying to do :

In the database I have shipment records A - G

I want to delete all the completed shipments. Shipments A - E are completed, but not F or G.

There are also several Invoices in the system.

Rules :

1. If a completed Shipment is part an Invoice that contains other Shipments that *aren't* completed, it can't be deleted
2. If a completed Shipment is part an Invoice that contains other Shipments that can't be *deleted*, it can't be deleted

   Problem :

   - Invoice I1 contains Shipments A, B and C. As those are all Completed, I *could* delete them all
   - Invoice I2 contains Shipments A, F and G. As F & G are *not* Completed, I can't delete *any* of them
   - BUT, because A cannot be deleted, by Rule 1, because it is part of Invoice I1, neither can B or C

...we'd then need to check any other invoices B & C are part of...

...and so on to infinity...

...and for the life of me I can't think of a simple, quick SQL statement or algorithm to do this other than by brute force ore recursion-until-end

Any alternative suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: As to your first two paragraphs, the only thing bad about the question is that you have all that at the beginning, so that's all that was visible on the summary page.  This means I had no real idea what the actual question was about.  But being a bit punch drunk (it's almost 5:30 AM here), I clicked on it anyway.  But, unfortunately, this is too complex for me to grok at this point.  So, I'll leave the answer for someone else.

Comment: what database server are you using (sql server / mysql oracle etc)? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet?

Comment: Hi MAP, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: MortB, it's for a team I'm working with - we're using SQLServer 2012. I *think* I've an idea how to tackle it - I've some pseudocode I'll try to post here ( when I can figure out how.. ) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea. Assuming you from your description that you have something like these three tables (SQL Server syntax below):

```
CREATE TABLE Invoice
(
   Id INT PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE Shipment
(
   Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   Completed BIT
)

CREATE TABLE Invoice_Shipment
(
   InvoiceId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Invoice(Id),
   ShipmentId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Shipment(Id)
)
```

You could then:

1. Delete "unnecessary" connections from the `Invoice_Shipment` table

   DELETE FROM Invoice_Shipment 
   WHERE InvoiceId NOT IN
      (SELECT InvoiceId FROM Invoice_Shipment 
       WHERE ShipmentId IN 
        (SELECT Id FROM Shipment WHERE Completed = 0))
2. Delete "not used" Shipments from the the `Shipment` table

   DELETE FROM Shipment 
   WHERE Completed = 1 AND Id NOT IN
      (SELECT InvoiceId FROM Invoice_Shipment)

Re write this to fit your needs and don't forget to wrap in transaction.

Comment: sorry for the SQL formatting in the later part of my post, I can't get it to format the SQL as code instead of text

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something like this - it was the recursion which was causing me the headache :

```
TRUNC Shipments_To_Delete

-- Grab all the 'Complete' Shipments
INSERT INTO Shipments_To_Delete
  ( SELECT * FROM Shipment WHERE Complete )

-- Make sure we iterate at least once
Shipments_To_Remove = True

WHILE Shipments_To_Remove

  -- Test if there's anything left to do..
  Shipments_To_Remove = 
    (
      -- Count if there are any Shipments marked for deletion..
      --   ..which can't be because they're part of an Invoice..
      --   ..which contains *other* Shipments that *can't* be deleted
      --
      SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Shipments_To_Delete WHERE Shipment_ID IN

        -- Find all the Shipments on Invoices that have Shipments that can't be deleted
        ( SELECT Shipment_ID FROM Invoice_Shipments WHERE Invoice_ID IN 

          -- Find all the Invoices that have Shipments which can't be deleted
          ( SELECT Invoice_ID FROM Invoice_Shipments WHERE Shipment_ID NOT IN
            ( SELECT Shipment_ID FROM Shipments_To_Delete )
          )

        )
     ) > 0

  IF Shipments_To_Remove THEN

    -- Reuse the query above to make it a DELETE
    --
    DELETE FROM Shipments_To_Delete WHERE Shipment_ID IN
      ( SELECT Shipment_ID FROM Invoice_Shipments WHERE Invoice_ID IN 
        ( SELECT Invoice_ID FROM Invoice_Shipments WHERE Shipment_ID NOT IN
          ( SELECT Shipment_ID FROM Shipments_To_Delete )
        )
      )

  ENDIF

-- If we've changed anything, loop around again and check whether there's anything left to do
DO
```